# In Glib 1.2 is it safe to remove items from a hashtable while using g_hash_table_foreach?

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

When using GLib 1.2's `GHashTable` with the `g_hash_table_foreach()` method, is it safe to remove items using the `g_hash_table_remove()` method?

I know that Glib 2.0 provides the `g_hash_table_foreach_steal()` method, but we're stuck with 1.2 for our build at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's not allowed in the current API, so I'd be really surprised if that functionality was there in 1.2.

Comment: Is the only way to keep a separate list of keys and remove them afterwards? That doesn't feel very clean at all.

Comment: @brice: It is one way and there's nothing wrong with it.  Another way would be to create a new hash table and add the key value pairs you want to *keep* to it as you go along.  Then at the end, replace the original hash table with the new one.

Comment: Thanks for answering and your follow up. You're right, of course, there isn't anything wrong with doing it either ways. I guess working with higher level languages like Python and Clojure has given me really lazy habits!